# I want to connect nodes the same number of times, but it ends up in an infinite loop

Tags: java, while-loop

```
class Solution<E> {
    public  Node<E> reproduceByN(Node<E> head, int n){
        Node<E> iter = head;
        for(int i = 0;i< n;i++){
            while(iter.next != null){
                iter = iter.next;
            }
            iter.next = head;
        }

        return head;

    }

}
```

The `reproduceByN` method attempts to connect nodes a specified number of times, but it encounters an infinite loop during the second iteration of the `while` loop.

The expected outcome was to traverse the nodes to the end in the `while` loop and then add the same nodes afterward, repeating this process for a specified number of times using the `for` loop. However, it unexpectedly enters an infinite loop midway, and I'm unsure about the solution.

Comment: Actually you just iterate once over the Queue, then connect its tail with its head. Of course you'll now get an infinite loop. To 'escape' the infinite loop, you have to extend your if a little bit: `while(iter.next != null && iter.next != head)`. But still, you will not 're-add' any other elements. What you should do instead is to 1) In a first loop, find the end ('tail') of the queue and save that to its own variable. 2) run your algorithm and in there, each time before you do `iter = iter.next;` you add the current node to the end of the tail (`tail.next = iter;`) and then ...

Comment: and then jump tail to the element `tail = iter`, then do `iter = iter.next;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is entering an infinite loop during the second iteration of the while loop is because you're not resetting the iter pointer to the head of the linked list after you've traversed it once. As a result, during the second iteration of the for loop, iter is already at the end of the list from the previous iteration, and the while loop condition iter.next != null is never satisfied, leading to an infinite loop.

To fix this issue, you need to reset the iter pointer to the head of the linked list before starting the next iteration of the for loop. Here's the corrected code:

```
class Solution<E> {
    public Node<E> reproduceByN(Node<E> head, int n) {
        Node<E> iter = head;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Traverse to the end of the linked list
            while (iter.next != null) {
                iter = iter.next;
            }
            
            // Connect the end of the list to the head
            iter.next = head;
            
            // Reset iter to the head for the next iteration
            iter = head;
        }
        
        return head;
    }
}
```

By resetting iter to head after each iteration of the for loop, you ensure that the while loop starts from the beginning of the list in each iteration, and the code should work as expected, connecting the nodes the specified number of times without entering an infinite loop.